# A query on Integration by parts formula (from Evans - Partial Differential Equation).

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, multiple-integral

From Evans Partial Differential Equation:

(Integration by parts formula). Let $u,v \in C^1(\bar U)$. Then 
$$\int_U u_{x_i} v dx = -\int_U v_{x_i}u dx + \int_{\partial U}uv\nu^idS \  \  \ (i= 1,... , n).$$

My question is: Since $u,v \in C^1(\bar U)$, it means $u,v \in C^1(U)$ and $u, v, Du, Dv$ are uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $U$, so the domain of $u,v$ is $U$
only, the domain does not include $\partial U$ (boundary of $U$). Then how to evaluate $\int_{\partial U}uv\nu^idS$?

Comment: $u,v\in C^1(\overline{U})$ means that the differentiable functions $u,v:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and their  derivatives have continuous extensions to $\overline{U}$ that take values on the boundary $\partial U$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, $u,v \in C^1(\bar{U})$ does mean $u,v,Du,Dv$ are uniformly continuous on $U$ (here, Evans assumes $U$ is bounded, so the "bounded" qualifier is unneeded) and $\partial U$ is not explicitly mentioned. It is a fact (from basic analysis) that every uniformly continuous function $f \in C(\bar{U})$ has a unique extension to a continuous function $f:\bar{U} \to \mathbb{R}$. If you are not familiar with this "fact", I can add details. This extension is what is used to define the integral over the boundary.

Comment: If $u'$ and $v'$ are continuous extensions of $u$ and $v$ respectively, it means $u'$ and $v'$ agree with $u$ and $v$ in $U$. So in the term $\int_{\partial U}uv\nu^idS$, in place of $u,v$ we should write $u', v'$.

Comment: Yes, but since the extension is unique, this detail is usually omitted.