# Is there a reason that test functions are chosen to have a compact support?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

If $f$ is a distribution, we choose test functions from $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$. My question is,

1. Is there a reason that we want test function to be smooth?
2. Why do we want the function to have a compact support? Can't we have replace the condition to be $f \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ (or $L^p$)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just some thoughts. By being smooth and compactly supported, we can define many natural operations on the dual space of the test functions. For instance, derivatives of all orders make sense for very "rough" objects, and even convolution in certain cases. By contrast, the dual space of $L^p$ is $L^{p'}$ ($p'$ the Hölder conjugate of $p$). This makes the test functions a nice class of functions to use for studying certain "weak" solutions to PDE, since it becomes very simple to define, and in many cases prove well-posedness, of a weak solution to a PDE (compared to classical solutions).

Comment: Integration by parts is used a lot in PDEs, see the formula in this post.  Notice that the boundary term can be made to be zero if we choose our sets "correctly". 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838337/a-query-on-integration-by-parts-formula-from-evans-partial-differential-equat

Comment: Also, being a small class of test functions, you get a large space of distributions, including some very singular ones. "Good" distributions can be extended to larger spaces of tests. So for example tempered distributions are the ones who admit a continuous extension to the Schwartz class of test functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. By having smooth test functions we can define derivatives of distributions of all orders:
   $$\langle u^{(k)}, \phi \rangle = (-1)^k \langle u, \phi^{(k)} \rangle.$$
2. By having test functions with compact support we can

   1. give distributions a local identity,
   2. make extremely rapidly growing functions like $e^{e^{x^2}}$ be distributions.